# Visual Studio 2010 form creation: fill an array with contents of a combobox

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, combobox

Trying to knock out a project that's hanging my code without re-writing the entire thing. In it, I just need to populate an array with the information already in the Names combobox in order to proceed. As I'm not using .NET, my options are limited.

(The end result)*Add a button named “btnShowBalance” displaying the text “ShowBalance.”  Write code in its event handler asking the user to enter a client’s name (InputBox).  Search the names array for the name entered.  If the name is found, use its location to retrieve the matching balance from the balances array.  Display the client’s name and balance if the client exists; otherwise, display a not-found message. ****

Public Class Form1

```
Dim Balances(7) As Decimal
Dim Names(7) As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    cboNames.Items.Add("John One")

    cboNames.Items.Add("Jack Two")

    cboNames.Items.Add("John Three")

    cboNames.Items.Add("Jack Four")

    cboNames.Items.Add("John Five")

    cboNames.Items.Add("Jack Six")

    cboNames.Items.Add("John Seven")

    cboNames.Items.Add("Jack Eight")

    cboBalances.Items.Add("235.50")

    cboBalances.Items.Add("78943.98")

    cboBalances.Items.Add("230781.10")

    cboBalances.Items.Add("78362.00")

    cboBalances.Items.Add("12097.20")

    cboBalances.Items.Add("89267.34")

    cboBalances.Items.Add("34959.06")

    cboBalances.Items.Add("559284.50")

    For i = 0 To cboNames.Items.Count - 1
        Names(i) = cboNames.Text
    Next
    For i = 0 To cboBalances.Items.Count - 1
        Names(i) = cboBalances.SelectedItem
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btnShowBalance_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShowBalance.Click
    Dim strResult As String
    strResult = InputBox("Enter the name of the customer", "Balance Finder")
    For i = 0 To Names.Length - 1
        If strResult = Names(i) Then
            MessageBox.Show(Names(i).ToString & " " & Balances(i).ToString)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Perhaps if you fill the right array you get the right answer.

Comment: -and that's what staring at it for too long will do to you ><. Thanks- but now I have another problem in that I need to retrieve items from cboBalances to assign to *its* array. .items won't allow a decimal conversion whereas I don't have the liberty to change the intended variable type